# mysql: get last success and last fail in one select

Tags: mysql

Goal:
Get the last success and the last fail in one select query:
Expected output:
bj, feature, name, env, lastSuccess, lastFail
(varchar(100), varchar(100), varchar(100), varchar(1), timestamp, timestamp)

```
bj1, ft1, example, a, 10-04-2017 16:19, 10-04-2017 15:20
bj1, ft1, example, t, 10-04-2017 16:19, 10-04-2017 15:20
```

Tabel script_status (source):
created, bj, feature, name, env, online, id
(timestamp, varchar(100), varchar(100), varchar(100), varchar(1), tinyint(1), int)

```
10-04-2017 16:19, bj1, ft1, example, a, 1, 900
10-04-2017 15:20, bj1, ft1, example, a, 0, 899

10-04-2017 16:19, bj1, ft1, example, t, 1, 898
10-04-2017 15:20, bj1, ft1, example, t, 0, 800
.
.
.

10-03-2017 16:19, bj1, ft1, example, a, 1, 600
10-03-2017 16:19, bj1, ft1, example, a, 0, 500
```

(online is 1 on success 0 on fail)

this is how far i got but this doesnt work

```
(select s.* from script_status s where s.id in (SELECT max(ss.id) as id from script_status ss group by ss.bj, ss.feature, ss.name, ss.env))
left JOIN

(select f.* as lastFailed from script_status f where f.id in (SELECT max(ff.id) as id from script_status ff where ff.online = 0 group by ff.bj, ff.feature, ff.name, ff.env)) on s.bj = f.bj and s.feature = f.feature and s.name = f.name
left JOIN

(select p.* as lastSuccess from script_status p where p.id in (SELECT max(pp.id) as id from script_status pp where pp.online = 1 group by pp.bj, pp.feature, pp.name, ff.env)) on s.bj = p.bj and s.feature = p.feature and s.name = p.name
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I don't see the point why it has to be one query, however you can use UNION to combine your queries

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query - and store dates using an appropriate data type.

Comment: I typed the example without the db next to me but the date field are stored (as is written between the brackeds) in a timestamp field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    `bj`,
    `feature`,
    `name`,
    `env`,
    (SELECT MAX(`created`) FROM `script_status` b WHERE a.`id` = b.`id` AND `online` = 1) as `lastSuccess`,
    (SELECT MAX(`created`) FROM `script_status` c WHERE a.`id` = c.`id` AND `online` = 0) as `lastFail`,
FROM `script_status` a
GROUP BY `bj`,`feature`,`name`,`env`
```

Comment: Thx it was not exactly where i was afther but i managed to get the data as i wanted by change the where clouse in the sub queries